# Finish runnable and start new activity

Tags: android

I have an app that starts with a class that has an instance of another class. The second class uses Runnable to show welcome to user.
I want to finish Runnable and start a new activity that navigates the user to Menu class that user can chooses different options. 
Runnable uses canvas to draw on screen its welcome messages.
Does anyone knows how to finish runnable and start Menu activity and set the view to Menu.xml that already exists in the layouts.

Comment: the runnable finish when the run is completed .

Answer (score 0):

Start an Activity which has contents to show **Welcome User**.. something like this..

```
Class Welcome extends Activity {

public void onCreate(){
//set content to welcome..

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

public void run(){
//start new ACtivity...
}

}, interval); //interval you want for showing welcome..
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me to get out of trouble.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider using async tasks. Using runnables in android is bad practice.

You can you async task method doInBackground to proceed with some calculations and onPostExecute will be called after that, so you can go there to your next activity.

Comment: "Using runnables in android is bad practice" who does told you that?

Comment: Android has his own ways for handling multi threading: handlers, loaders, asynctask. Using simple runnable is a primitive solution(IMHO), you can read about all this in official documentation.

Comment: no it does not. AsyncTask is a facility of high level built on the Executor framework. Using AsyncTask is good. Is Thread is good too. All depends on your purpose.

Comment: Well you have your opinion, I have mine. I was always able to avoid in smooth way custom runnables using only async task and loaders, so I found them really good.

Comment: then you should say "in my opinion" is a bad idea and explain why it is a bad idea (IMHO)

Comment: I suppose we shouldn't argue about my comment(it will bring us to long discussion). It's more reasonable to help user1343573 with his issue.